# Equivalent for App\Model::with('relation') in Laravel 7.x controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

In my controller i return a json object with:

```php
  public function show(Comic $comic)
  {
    //
    return Comic::with('series')->findOrFail($comic->comic_id);
  }
```

Is there a shorter form to gain the same output? I was thinking about

```php
  public function show(Comic $comic)
  {
    //
    return $comic->with('series');
  }
```

But this does not work and throws the error:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, there is such a thing as "Lazy Eager Loading":

```
$comic->load('series');
```

That loads that relationship for you on the Model instance you already have so you don't have to query for that model again. `load` returns the model instance so you can return the result from the call as the model instance.

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Eager Loading - Lazy Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) `load`

Comment: Thanks (and sorry). I should have read that chapter in the documentation more carefully.